# Help understanding remaining HDD space

Tags: mount, hard-drive, lvm

So I'm trying to figure out if I can use a good chunk of hdd space that appears to be unmounted in my system.

```
lsblk
    NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
    loop0                       7:0    0  74.1M  1 loop  /snap/core22/1033
    loop1                       7:1    0  73.9M  1 loop  /snap/core22/864
    loop2                       7:2    0 180.9M  1 loop  /snap/lxd/25846
    loop3                       7:3    0 152.1M  1 loop  /snap/lxd/26200
    loop4                       7:4    0  40.9M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/20290
    loop5                       7:5    0  40.4M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/20671
    sda                         8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
    ├─sda1                      8:1    0     1G  0 part  /boot/efi
    ├─sda2                      8:2    0     2G  0 part  /boot
    └─sda3                      8:3    0 462.7G  0 part
      └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 252:0    0   100G  0 lvm   /
    sdb                         8:16   0  12.7T  0 disk
    └─sdb1                      8:17   0  12.7T  0 part
      └─md127                   9:127  0  25.5T  0 raid5 /mnt/raid1
    sdc                         8:32   0  12.7T  0 disk
    └─sdc1                      8:33   0  12.7T  0 part
      └─md127                   9:127  0  25.5T  0 raid5 /mnt/raid1
    sdd                         8:48   0  12.7T  0 disk
    └─sdd1                      8:49   0  12.7T  0 part
      └─md127                   9:127  0  25.5T  0 raid5 /mnt/raid1
```

What I'm looking at is the sda3 partition. I see the 100G used and 462.8G still listed above. I have attempted to find a mount point for the remaining space but at this point I'm not sure what I'm even looking at.

Is that space usable? Can I extend the lvm mount? If is is usable, where is it mounted?

```
df -h

Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              1.6G  5.8M  1.6G   1% /run
efivarfs                           256K  140K  112K  56% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   98G   29G   64G  32% /
tmpfs                              7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          2.0G  124M  1.7G   7% /boot
/dev/sda1                          1.1G  6.1M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
/dev/md127                          26T  637G   24T   3% /mnt/raid1
tmpfs                              1.6G  4.0K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Attempting to find the mount results in no output

```
findmnt /dev/sda3
```

But I think I can find the root mount and the 100G

```
 findmnt / --df
SOURCE                            FSTYPE  SIZE  USED AVAIL USE% TARGET
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4   97.9G 28.9G 63.9G  30% /
```

Anyway, since this is my root drive I don't want to make any changes until I fully understand what I'm looking at.  So to sum it up, how can I use that remaining ~300G of space?

Comment: Best to learn about LVM or volumes which are in partitions. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm & https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM  I do not use LVM, but I understand it is easy to expand but difficult to shrink. So installer does not use entire space in case you want it for other volumes, /home, data, or other installs.

Answer (score 0):

as it appears you are using LVM in your setup. From this perspective i would suggest to use LVM to use entire space on sda3.
Here is [one guide](https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/) i found.

When using "mount"-command, you can see, what actual is mounted in your system. And, you want find sda3, as this partition is not mounted right now (now mount point in lsblk output.)

/etc/fstab contains information about all filesystems your system should be able to (auto)mount.

Hope this helps a bit.